# why this code can't create a sequelize association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i am trying to create a database with sequelize-cli and make a hasMany association, but for some reason i can't populate data in the second table

i was thinking if the association was really created, on my sgbd i don't see that "key", the foreign key representation;
i was showing this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xJLcTxlEIs
but only my doenst work, just show this error:

```
Listening on port 5000
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `categoria` (`id`,`nomept`,`nomeen`,`nomefr`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);
Unhandled rejection TypeError: cate.createFaqs is not a function
    at Categoria.create.then.cate (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/server.js:13:10)
    at tryCatcher (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/coyas/software_center/wifyanywhere/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

my server code:

```
const Categoria = require('./models').categoria
const Faqs = require('./models').faqs

Categoria.create({
    nomept: 'terrs',
    nomeen: 'sqsdqs',
    nomefr: 'fdds'
}).then( cate => {
    cate.createfaqs({
        title: "teste terra",
        descricao: "dqsdsddqs dsd qd qd qdqq"
    }).then( () => console.log('funcionou'))
})
```

other code:

- faqs.js: https://pastebin.com/4ww06n8k
- categoria.js: https://pastebin.com/c8gD2GMG
- migation/...faqs.js: https://pastebin.com/kWYMxQxf
- migration/...categoria.js: https://pastebin.com/5J8ZYnAS

i expect that the cate.createFaqs()   work and put some data into table with categoriaId belong to table categoria

Comment: Well its clear for me `cate.createFaqs is not a function`, check a cate object for a function, you can use debugger or console `console.log(cate.__proto__)` and look for a create method, my guess is it will by `createFaq`

Comment: You're right, but you gave the error because in db it looks for categoriumId (why?  "i have categoriaId").
But my biggest problem is because in the db does not show the reference of the foreign key?

Comment: see the table, do not have the foreign key reference (the gray key)
https://pasteboard.co/ImKAOMR.png

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, just had to add this line of code:

references: {
          model: 'Categories',
          key: 'id' 
        },

inside the migration code, and voila!